# How to Reboot a Server in a Failover Cluster

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster

We have a failover cluster manager managing 4 node(host) servers. How would I go about rebooting one of the nodes in the failover cluster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. login to the HyperV host
2. select `Start> Administrative tools> Failover Cluster Manager`
3. Select `Failover Cluster Manager`
4. Verify which server you need to restart (You can check the roles to see which host server, 'node', owns which guest server, 'role')
5. Select `Nodes`, right click the desired server, and select `Drain Roles` (NOTE: make sure to verify the resources available to ensure the roles can be drained without causing issue. eg. enough RAM, CPU)
6. Verify that the Roles have migrated successfully by selecting the Node, and navigating to the Roles tab
7. Reboot the desired host
8. after the reboot has successfully taken place, navigate back to `Failover Cluster Manager> Nodes>` Right click and select `Fail Roles Back`

Comment: I am marking this as the answer, but please do reach out if there are any prerequisites, or cautions to take into account.

Comment: Another answer mentions that the node should be paused. Is the pause step unnecessary?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Failover Cluster Manager
2. Make sure that all disks are not located on the node which has to reboot
3. Migrate all roles and VMs
4. Pause node in Nodes tab
5. If you don't know the IP of the remote host, you can right-click on the needed host and choose remote desktop. Then just simply reboot it as any other server/pc.